# Chiral anomaly in odd spacetime dimensions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-anomalies, chirality

In odd number of space-time dimensions, the Fermions are not reducible (*i.e.* do not have left-chiral and right-chiral counterparts).

Does this mean that there is no such thing as 'chiral' anomalies in odd number of space-time dimensions, when these fermions are coupled to gauge fields?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no [chiral anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly)/[gauge anomaly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_anomaly) if the spacetime dimension $2\ell+1$ is odd, partly because $SO(2\ell+1)$ has real or pseudo-real representations, but no complex representations.

There may instead be [parity anomalies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_anomaly) in odd spacetime dimensions. In fact, there is a dimensional ladder of related anomalies

$$\text{Abelian chiral anomaly in}~ 2\ell+2~ \text{dimensions}$$
$$ \downarrow$$
$$\text{Parity anomaly in}~ 2\ell+1~ \text{dimensions}$$
$$ \downarrow$$
$$\text{Non-Abelian anomaly in}~ 2\ell~ \text{dimensions}.$$

See e.g. M. Nakahara, *Geometry, Topology and Physics,* Section 13.6.

Comment: awesome answer, was trying to figure out why myself!

Comment: Awesome!!  What's a non-abelian anomaly?  Is there an example of it in the Standard Model?