# Why Parity Anomaly in Odd Dimensions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, parity, quantum-anomalies

In section 13.6 of Nakahara, the parity anomaly is in odd dimensional spacetime.

From the paper [Fermionic Path Integral And Topological Phases](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04715) by Witten, the problem appears as one cannot define the sign of the path integral,

$$S[\bar{\psi},\psi;A]=\int d^{2n+1}x\bar{\psi}iD \!\!\!\!/\,\psi,$$
$$\mathcal{Z}=\det(iD \!\!\!\!/\,)=\prod_{\lambda\in\mathrm{spec}}\lambda,$$

because there are infinite number of positive and negative eigenvalues $\lambda$.

The number of eigenvalues flowing through $\lambda=0$ is related with the index theorem in $2n+2$ dimenions.

***Does the  partiy anomaly appear in even dimensions?***

***From Nakahara's derivation, I don't see anything related with the dimension of spacetime. If this anomaly exists in odd dimensions, then why doesn't it appear in even dimensions?***

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/43317/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Is there parity anomaly in even dimensions?

Comment: Mass terms are parity invariant in even dimensions only. Thus, Pauli-Villars (which consists of introducing very massive ghost fields) may only cause an anomaly in odd dimensions.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you for your comment. Would you please elaborate the first sentence "Mass terms are parity invariant in even dimensions only." in the answer. Thanks a lot.